# Div To Grow With Content Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, json

I have a div called #devices and I use ajax to populate it, but I'm having a bit of a styling problem, I append a json to the devices div like this:

```
$('#devices').html(json);
```

I set the width of the devices in my css like this:

```
#devices
{
    border:thin solid #C7C7C7;
    padding:20px;
    width:600px;
}
```

I'm not sure what the width is going to be of the content since it can change when a user changes an element in a select box, how do I make it so the text will wrap inside the 600px-wide div?

Right now the content is printed on one huge line that extends across the page and out of the div,

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample page that shows this or post the html/css I suspect it has to do with the styling of the content but can't know without a more complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`whitespace: pre-wrap`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html).

Alternately, instead of inserting the JSON string directly into the `#devices` div, why not use [jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl).[tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) or [some](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) [other](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) [JavaScript](http://beebole.com/pure/) templating engine to generate HTML for your devices list?

Comment: Hm wow I wasn't even aware of Jquery.tmpl but it looks like something I could use thank you! I'll mark correct asap :)

Comment: I don't believe IE supports pre-wrap...mabye IE8+ does

Comment: @zzzBov -- correct, IE8+ does.  (The `whitespace: pre-wrap` is actually a link to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html which contains a compatibility table.)

Answer (score 0):

Text will automatically wrap inside the div using the standard `whitespace` CSS setting (defaults to `normal`). Note that text never 'wraps' in the middle of non-word boundaries, such as a very long string of characters like xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.

Is it this degenerate user input case that you are concerned about? If so, set `overflow:auto` (for scrollbars) or `overflow:hidden` (for clipping) to prevent the text from escaping your container.